# Ubuntu 14.04 Server: Apache2 issue with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server, apache2

I have installed Apache 2, and it is working fine. I have installed PHP 7, and everything works fine, But when I install phpMyAdmin, Apache 2 stops working. When checking Apache 2, it even does not load the default page.

When I restart Apache 2, the following error comes up:

```
root@ip-172-31-30-202:~# service apache2 restart
* Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                   [fail]
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The error log has:

```
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:10.668017 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13665:tid 140077033654144] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:10.668089 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13665:tid 140077033654144] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:23.642421 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13665:tid 140077033654144] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:24.689367 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14802] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:24.689425 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14802] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:25.869852 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14802] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:26.942086 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14888] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 12:54:26.942120 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14888] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 12:55:36.014664 2016] [:error] [pid 14891] [client 103.255.6.72:60140] script '/var/www/html/info1.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jul 18 12:56:38.672883 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14888] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/simplexml.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/wddx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlreader.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xmlwriter.so: cannot open shared object file: No$
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/xsl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file o$
[Mon Jul 18 12:56:39.724500 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14954] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 12:56:39.724533 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14954] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 12:57:41.945362 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14954] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Jul 18 12:57:42.017483 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14954] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 12:57:42.017497 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14954] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 12:57:42.610599 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14954] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 18 13:02:11.030749 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20227] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 13:02:11.030808 2016] [core:notice] [pid 20227] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 13:05:14.256971 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20227] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 18 13:05:34.584056 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21762] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 13:05:34.584096 2016] [core:notice] [pid 21762] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 13:08:45.103877 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21762] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Jul 18 13:08:45.197300 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21762] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 18 13:08:45.197313 2016] [core:notice] [pid 21762] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 18 13:08:45.779038 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21762] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

I am using [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr).

Comment: you should check the error log. go to /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by uninstalling Apache 2:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

The I installed phpMyAdmin:

```
sudo apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
```

Then I installed `apache2`:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me:

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
rm php5.conf 
rm php5.load 

sudo service apache2 start;
```

It worked :)))))

See also *[apache2 segfault after update](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=227498)*.

Comment: I don't know how or why, but your solution just worked for me as well.

Comment: I tried to install phpmyadmin with PHP 7.1 already installed, then it tried to do weird stuff with php5 :( This solution worked for me.

Comment: Works for me , you saved my day :) :)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for saving me the headache of having to reconfigure my whole server again :D

Comment: I dont know why either but this solution also worked for me wow man your a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Run these command in the terminal:

```
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Add the following to the bottom of the file:

```
# phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache does not dump core by default. Have a look at http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/.